# Sed substitution - spaces by tabs

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to formatting a batch of .c files via the `sed` command in a shell script to align properly the functions name. I'm replacing `int(space)function1()` by `int(3tab)function1()`

```
int         function1(int foo)
{
    *my_function_code*
}

char        function2(int foo)
{
    *my_function_code*
}

int         main(int foo)
{
    *my_function_code*
}
```

I'm actually using the following loop to apply my substitution :

```
#align global scope
printf " Correct global scope alignement...\n"
for file in ${FILES[@]}; do
sed -i -e 's/^int */int         /g' \
    -i -e 's/^char */char       /g' \
    -i -e 's/^float */float     /g' \
    -i -e 's/^long int */long int   /g' ${file}
done
```

The problem is, if I rerun the script, instead of doing nothing, it will add multiple tabs again. Giving me this :

```
int                     function1(int foo)
{
    *my_function_code*
}

char                    function2(int foo)
{
    *my_function_code*
}

int                     main(int foo)
{
    *my_function_code*
}
```

The  `*` isn't supposed to looking only for spaces and not tabulations or is it considered as all blanks characters ?

Comment: So why not use a specialized tool to indent C code? Like `indent` for example

Comment: C tag removed as irrelevant

Comment: Don't try to do this with sed or any other text-processing tool, there are plenty of C beautifier tools out there that will be far more robust. 3 tabs between the return type and the function name would just obfuscate the code and make the parameter lists wrap around unnecessarily though. Stick to an existing style that one of the beautifiers will output for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Simply checking if line starts either from `int` or `char`(you could add float and long int too in condition) then substitute spaces in 3 tabs here.

```
sed -E '/^int|^char/s/ +/\t\t\t/'  Input_file
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine for but now, it adds 3 tabs to the parameters
```int         func(char            c)```

Comment: @Korkrane, it was written and tested with shown samples only, if you have more conditions or checks then please do add them because solutions given on SO are samples specific only, please do let us know on same

Comment: #Korkrane sounds like you added a `g` to the end of the sed command.